What battery connector does the Playdate console use?
I'm trying to figure out what battery connector the Playdate console (https://play.date) uses, for replacement and other modding purposes. I've looked through many manufacturer catalogs like Molex, JST, TE, and Hirose without any matches. I've also been unable to find a match looking through all seemingly-relevant connectors on the popular component resellers. Hopefully I'm just missing something obvious!
The connector has 3 pins at 1.25mm pitch, and I've included a couple photos + an approximate dimensioned drawing based off my own measurements.




Power hungry moderators like to remove things for no reason, so re-adding here for further discussion: Per the selected answer, it looks like Playdate uses the Amphenol 10125836-03-001. However, this line has been discontinued, and Amphenol doesn't offer a drop-in replacement. Alternatives welcome!

See my updated answer

@RohatKılıç thanks, but unfortunately 10125836-03-001SP is also obsolete, as well as the matching wire to board connector 10125839-03RAEHLF. I even contacted Amphenol directly to ask about a replacement, and they said "There are no drop-in replacement parts available".

I'm not a moderator, I'm a regular user.  I edited the shopping request out of your question because it's off-topic (so is 'discussion' - both of which you should know by now, considering you've been a member for 3.5 years). Feel free to revert the edit and I'll happily give you a VTC instead if that's what you prefer.

@PaulStraw oh, just noticed that. Digikey has some stock, though, if you need.

I've found a very similar one. All the dimensions match except the pitch. It's 1.2 mm, not 1.25 mm.
EDIT: The one I linked above appears to be obsolete. But Digikey automatically offered a substitute which seems to be identical but also obsolete (facepalm).

This appears to be correct, thank you!
